# Is there a way to start creating an archive while the files are still being downloaded?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, zip, archive

I'm downloading around 5 videos simultaneously (with `wget` on linux through php exec) and am wanting to start archiving (make one file) of them all as they download.

At the moment when I try:

```
zip archive.zip file1 file2 file3
```

The `archive.zip` contains the files exactly as they were when the archiving commenced.

Is there a way this can be done or do I have to wait until all the files have fully finished downloading before they can be archived?

No compression is needed.

The reason I'm wanting to do this is so that the end user / client can begin downloading their `archive.zip` almost instantaneously opposed to waiting 20 seconds.

Comment: Are you using some sort of loop to poll whether or not files are completely downloaded? If so could you post some of that logic to your answer.